# How in c# to convert a string of comma-separated bracket-enclosed (nested) comma-separated values into a List of Lists?

Tags: c#

Given a  string like

```
"(5678, 2, 41, 3), (4852, 8, 3, 97), (4562, 85, 3, 7)"
```

How in c# can I turn that into a List (or  array) of the three parent values, each of which being a List (or array) of its four child values?

I'm thinking that I want to end up with a `List<List<int>>` if that makes sense.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I think that using `string.Split` and loops can help

Comment: WHilst I have provided an answer that offers an appropriate level of help to this "do my homework for me" style of question, I still feel these questions should be closed, so have voted to do so.

Comment: @wudzik: I have thought of `Split (')')`, but would the have to get rid of the `, (` in each element, no? I have thought of `Split (',')`, but that would break down the nesting, or would it not?

Comment: @user1930469 split by `), (` to 3 separate strings and then split these strings by `,` with trimming `(`, so you will have `List<List<string>>` then parse to int and voila

Comment: @user1930469 consider showing your previous efforts in your question and highlight the points you are going to know.

Comment: @wudzik: thanks, first split leaves `(`  at the beginning of the first element and `)` at the end of the last so presumbly I have to use `Replace` to get rid of those characters. I was wondering if there might some more straight forward technique.

Comment: Thanks to wudzik's tips, I've figured out that the first split can be done with `Split(new string[] {"), (", "(", ")"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Answer (score 1):

May not be the best solution but it will work. Here is the code:

```
string value = "(5678, 2, 41, 3), (4852, 8, 3, 97), (4562, 85, 3, 7)";

var result = value
               .Split(')')
               .Select(i => i.Replace('(', ' '))
               .Select(i => i.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
               .ToList()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regex to split the string up into (p1), (p2), (p3) and then a simple string.Split() to access to the child values for each parent.