# c# - cast array list in a string to an array list

Tags: c#, serialization, arraylist

I have a string variable like so, which I am receiving from a third party API:

```
string strArray = "[[1,\"56353657\",\"300\",\"test\",\"<img src=\\\"../Images/Edit.gif\\\" id=\\\"Edit\\\" />\",\"<img src=\\\"../Images/Delete.gif\\\" id=\\\"Delete\\\" />\"],[2,\"56353657\",\"400\",\"test\",\"<img src=\\\"../Images/Edit.gif\\\" id=\\\"Edit\\\" />\",\"<img src=\\\"../Images/Delete.gif\\\" id=\\\"Delete\\\" />\"]]";
```

I would like to be able to loop through this and retrieve the first 3 items in each of the arrays. 
Could someone please advise me as to how to achieve this using c#?

Comment: This isn't just a string. This appears to be a JSON representation of an array of arrays. Try searching on how to *deserialize* JSON into C# objects.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178983/how-in-c-sharp-to-convert-a-string-of-comma-separated-bracket-enclosed-nested

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, it does appear to be a JSON representation of an array of arrays. But all the help sites are expecting the JSON to be in the key:value format, which this isnt in.

Comment: It's a JSON *array*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because values in your array of arrays are not of the same type you can try this way:

```
String[][] table = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<String[][]>(strArray);
```

Then you can loop through this and, if you need, convert values to the desired type.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks :)